# android different handler different activities

Tags: java, android, service, handler

My Android app contains different activities. Some of them have handlers like this:

```
private final Handler messagesHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message receivedMessage) {
        switch (receivedMessage.what) {
            case xxxx:
        }
    }
};
```

I have also an Activity that simulates a Service and send messages to the activity. Unfortunately, when I send messages, every message arrives to all Activities.

How can I send a message to a determinate activity?

Comment: may be you are using same Handler for all Activities

Comment: @MageshPandian no. I have declared different handler in every activity.

Comment: how do you send messages?

Comment: Hi if it helps your cause you might want to check out these links https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus and http://square.github.io/otto/.

Comment: I believe your problem is ur creating Handlers for each activity from the main thread & not attaching looper to them. So all your handlers are sharing the same message queue. You might want to checkout HandlerThread.